# Suma de ítems de un objeto JSON con angular 1.X

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

hola quiero sumar las cantidades de los items de un objeto desde el template. Sumar todas las edades de las personas en el siguiente objeto.

```
$scope.people=[{name:'juan',age:12},{name:'juan',age:12}];
```

> Y en el template

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
       <td>{{person.name}}</td>
       <td>{{person.age}}</td>
     </tr>
   <tfooter>
     <tr>
       <td>
         Años de las personas {{ aqui la suma de edad de personas}}
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tfooter>
</table>
```

Comment: [JSON != Objeto Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: Tienes un array, puedes simplemente hacer `{{people.reduce((acc,item) =>  acc +item.age, 0)}}`

Comment: Por otro lado, te recomiendo visitar el [tour] de bienvenida de SOes :)

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez esto funcione....(también soy nuevo en esto).

```
     $scope.suma = function(){
        var total = 0;
        for(var i=0; i< $scope.people.length; i++){
              var edad = $scope.people[i].age;
              total += edad;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

y en la vista solo usas esto...

```
    <tfooter>
      <tr>
          <td>
               Años de las personas {{suma()}}
        </td>
     </tr>
    </tfooter>
```

Comment: esto debería funcionar....