# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre JSON y un objeto?

Tags: javascript, json

A menudo se utilizan indistintamente los términos *JSON* y *objeto* (e incluso *objeto JSON* cuando hablamos de una estructura de datos, sobre todo en contextos relacionados con AJAX.

- ¿Cuál es la direfencia entre ambos?
- ¿Es *un JSON* un objeto Javascript o es otra cosa?

Comment: pregunta relacionada [¿Cómo puedo convertir un string JSON a un objeto en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1648/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-convertir-un-string-json-a-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Asumo que el lector tiene unos conocimientos básicos de Javascript:

```
//así declaramos un objeto básico en Javascript
let objeto={ atributo: 'valor'}
```

### No son lo mismo

**[JSON](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)** es el acrónimo de **JavaScript Object Notation**, es un formato de texto ligero para el intercambio de datos. ¿Qué quiere decir esto? Bueno, si vemos el siguiente texto

```
<lista-nodos>
  <nodo id="1">texto1</nodo>
  <nodo id="3">texto2</nodo>
  <nodo id="5">texto1</nodo>
</lista-nodos>
```

Todo programador tiene claro que eso es un texto *en formato XML*. Pues bien, JSON no es más que un formato distinto pero con la misma función. El equivalente a ese XML podría ser algo como:

```
[
  { "id": "1", "valor": "texto1"},
  { "id": "3", "valor": "texto2"},
  { "id": "5", "valor": "texto1"}
]
```

Como su propio nombre indica, esta notación es similar a la que usaríamos **en Javascript para crear un objeto**:

```js
const datos=[
  { id: "1", valor: "texto1"},
  { id: "3", valor: "texto2"},
  { id: "5", valor: "texto1"}
];

datos.forEach(dato=> console.log('elemento:',dato.id,dato.valor))
console.info("tipo de dato=", typeof(datos))
```

Pero un JSON es, y aquí me estoy repitiendo, **texto**:

```js
//esto es un texto en formato JSON
const datosJson=`[
  { "id": "1", "valor": "texto1"},
  { "id": "3", "valor": "texto2"},
  { "id": "5", "valor": "texto1"}
]`;

console.log(datosJson);
console.info("tipo de dato=", typeof(datosJson))
```

El formato JSON es algo más restrictivo de lo que sería el código Javascript:

- Todos los valores de tipo *string* deben ir entre comillas dobles, las comillas simples no están permitidas.
- Del mismo modo, todas las claves (los nombres de los atributos) deben ir entre comillas dobles.
- No admite ningún tipo de comentarios (a diferencia de XML, donde podemos usar `<!-- Comentarios-->`)
- Los valores numéricos han de estar en base decimal, no admite ceros a la izquierda (que pudieran pensar que el número está en base octal).
- No se admiten valores `undefined`.

Y, ¿cómo transformamos el texto en un objeto manipulable? ¿Y cómo hacemos la operación inversa?

Usando las siguientes funciones:

- `JSON.parse(<texto>)` nos devuelve un objeto creado a partir de un string que esté en formato JSON.
- `JSON.stringify(obj)` nos devuelve un string en formato JSON con los atributos del objeto `obj`. Si `obj` tiene atributos que sean funciones, serán ignorados.

```js
//texto con formato inválido
const datosJson=`[
  { "id": "1", valor: "texto1"},
  { "id": "3", valor: "texto2"},
]`;
try {
  const datos=JSON.parse(datosJson);
} catch(error) {
  console.log('Falla porque las claves valor no está entre comillas')
}
const datosJson2=`[
  { "id": 1, "valor": "texto1"},
  { "id": 3, "valor": "texto2"},
  { "id": 5, "valor": "texto1"}
]`;
//transformamos a objeto
const d=JSON.parse(datosJson2);
console.log(d[0].id);

//añadimos un elemento
d.push({id:4,valor:'otro texto'});

//transformamos el objeto de nuevo a JSON
console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
```

Por tanto, aunque JSON tenga como origen el lenguaje Javascript, no es más que una forma de enviar datos entre aplicaciones, que no necesariamente estarán implementadas con Javascript: cualquier lenguaje de programación puede procesar un JSON (al igual que un XML) para obtener la información necesaria.

Dos ejemplos cotidianos del uso de JSON son:

- AJAX: Cuando mandamos o recibimos datos desde un servidor, la información se suele mandar como texto plano, no podemos mandar un objeto como datos binarios si el lenguaje que los recibe no va a saber interpretarlos (muchas veces, al pedir recursos a un API de terceros, no sabemos siquiera qué lenguaje de programación se usó).
- Web Storage: Cuando queremos guardar datos en el navegador del usuario, usando el `localStorage` o el `sessionStorage`, los métodos `setItem` y `getItem` sólo trabajan con el tipo `string`, con lo que es necesario transformar los objetos que queremos guardar a texto.

Comment: Pablo, interesante pregunta/respuesta. JSON tiene más limitaciones en casos particulares. En el pasado [tuve problemas con enteros que necesitaba con ceros a la izquierda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139850/29967) y también [con los valores nulos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/140684/29967). No quita que JSON sea hoy día uno de los inventos más útiles, algo sencillo pero que es parte de la revolución de la informática, según mi humilde opinión.

Comment: Iré actualizando la respuesta, aún es un *work in progress*, gracias por esos detalles

Comment: Agregando un poco a tu respuesta el como saber cual es el [standard de un JSON](https://www.json.org/json-es.html), y segun ecmaScript  la [construccion de un objeto](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects)

Comment: @PabloLozano Sería bueno añadir al inicio un par de cosas. Introducir el concepto de:  
1. ```Object``` Def: Conjunto de elementos que están formados mediante pares de ```{```clave ```Key``` : valor ```Value``` ```}``` siendo el valor un dato u otro objeto.  
2. ```Array``` Def: Subconjunto de elementos ```Object``` en los que la clave ```Key``` en un numero natural ```Index```. Se da por supuesto que las índices ```Index```están ordenadas en orden creciente y sin huecos. ¡El conjunto de los números naturales empieza en "cero" ```0```! Y es la razón de que se use como 1º  índice  
... Cont

Comment: ... cont  
3. Def: El primitivo *Elemento base* de todo objeto es un objeto vacío ```Null === Objetct { : }``` y debido a ello el tipo ```typeOf``` de ```Null``` es ```Object```  
4. Def: Los objetos *JSON* Es un subconjunto de los ```Object``` en los que aplican ciertas reglas *mostrar el enlace a https://www.json.org/json-es.html*  
5. En javaScript y otros lenguajes afines existen dos métodos para convertir de *JSON*  a ```OBJECT``` y viceversa.

Answer (score 4):

Yo quisiera dar una respuesta más coloquial, algo que podrías dar como ejemplo a un no programador o principiante.

**- Objeto:** se circunscribe al código, se inicializa y se trabaja con el objeto durante la ejecución de un programa. El objeto estará formateado según las reglas semánticas del correspondiente lenguaje (orientado a objetos) en el que está escrito el código en el que se definen los objetos.

**- JSON:** es el 'archivo' que se usa como input-output, para inicializar o guardar estados o valores de un objeto y como es un 'estándar', tiene sus propias reglas semánticas definidas. Esta estandarización del formato hace que JSON tenga compatibilidad entre diferentes lenguajes de programación.

Comment: *algo que podrías dar como ejemplo a un no programador* -> Si está en SO se asume que es para programadores. Además, en la pregunta se especificó claramente `objeto Javascript` con lo cual *El objeto estará formateado según las reglas semánticas del correspondiente lenguaje (orientado a objetos) en el que esta escrito el código en el que se definen los objetos* no hace referencia a lo preguntado.

Comment: Entiendo tu comentario pero por como se formula la pregunta en el título me hace pensar que aquí podrían llegar personas principiantes o simplemente ante la duda, solo todo objeto es JSON.