# ¿Se pueden introducir caracteres especiales de un JSON?

Tags: html, json

¿Cómo puedo introducir caracteres especiales dentro de un JSON?
Por ejemplo si tengo:

```
{
    "a": "Hola mundo"
}
```

y quiero meter entre comillas la palabra "mundo".
Probe escapandolas y con el código HTML: " 
El string lo muestro en una página web, pero ninguna de las dos opciones funciono, no se si por la librería que lo carga o es algo inherente al uso de JSON.

> Editado:

Comillas escapadas: `\"`

No plantee adecuadamente la pregunta. Veo que mi problema es cosa de la librería ***ngx-translate*** para ***Angular2***, no por el JSON en sí. Esta librería almacena las traducciones en fichero JSON, pero no me ha permitido introducir comillas dobles dentro de las mismas como he indicado antes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Según el estándar que maneja [JSON.org](https://www.json.org/json-es.html) para el uso de cadenas o `String`,
Los valores deben empezar con una **`"`** para usar un caracter valido exceptuendo la comilla doble se debe usar la barra invertida **`\`** y despues de ella el caracter de control que necesitas obviamente finalizando con **`"`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algunos JSON validos

```js
let comillaDoble = {
    "a": "comilla \"doble\""
}
let comillaSimple = {
    "a": "comilla \'simple\'"
}
let saltoCarro = {
    "a": "\t tab \n Enter"
}
let barras = {
    "a": "barra1\\\/barra2 \u00F1"
}

console.log(comillaDoble.a,comillaSimple.a)
console.log(saltoCarro.a)
console.log(barras.a)
```

ahora bien que significa ese **`\u`**, para que sirve?  simple se utiliza para los caracteres especiales llamese eñes acentos entre otros en [formato unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).

```js
miJson = {
"resultado":  "1 es \u003C 2 ", 
}
console.log(miJson.resultado)
```

Un ejemplo de cuando usamos Unicode es cuando enviamos las respuestas via GET
el parametro lo transformamos a unicode con el comando [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent)

> Te invito a leer las [diferencias entre un JSON y un Objeto en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/164944/28035)

Answer (score 8):

Si se puede, solo debes usar una barra invertida (`\`) delante de las comillas, no sera valido si no presenta comillas de apertura y cierre.

Asi:

```
{
   "a": "Hola \"mundo\""
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Te dejo estas dos soluciones:

```
{
    "a": "Hola \"mundo\""
}
```

De lo contrario puedes probar:

```
{
    'a': 'Hola "mundo"'
}
```

Y si experimentas algún otro problema utiliza la función JSON.parse, una vez tengas tu objeto correctamente almacenado en tu script.

Comment: La primera opción es correcta para un JSON, la segunda no lo es.

Comment: Totalmente, esta fuera del esquema pero fue planteado como workaround en caso de continuar obteniendo errores al escapar como se deberia, al igual que la utilizacion de JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

En JSON al igual que con cualquier otro string existen cadenas de escape que permiten insertar caracteres especiales como: el salto de línea, la tabulación, las tildes, entre otros...
Y para este cas en particular se debe colocar el backslach seguido por el caracter que se quiere tomar como cadena (\")...

```
{
    "a": "\"Hola mundo\""
}
```