# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un nuevo elemento a un objeto json?

Tags: javascript, json

Me gustaría saber como puedo agregar un elemento al `json` :

```
let datos = [
    { "id": 197, "entrada": "07:00:00", "salida": "18:00:00", "descanso": "02:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-02", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
    { "id": 198, "entrada": "21:00:00", "salida": "23:00:00", "descanso": "00:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-03", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
    { "id": 199, "entrada": "21:30:00", "salida": "00:00:00", "descanso": "00:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-05", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
    { "id": 200, "entrada": "01:00:00", "salida": "05:00:00", "descanso": "00:30:00", "fecha": "2018-10-08", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
    { "id": 201, "entrada": "03:00:00", "salida": "08:00:00", "descanso": "01:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-09", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" }
];
```

Me gustaría recorrer ese array y en cada `json` agregar un nuevo valor llamado `cantidad` con un valor dinámico que lo tomaré de la resta de `entrada` y `salida`.

Un resultado parecido a este pero haciendolo de forma dinámica :

```
let datos = [
    { "id": 197, "entrada": "07:00:00", "salida": "18:00:00", "descanso": "02:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-02", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017", 'cantidad' : '00:00:00'},
    { "id": 198, "entrada": "21:00:00", "salida": "23:00:00", "descanso": "00:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-03", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017", 'cantidad' : '00:00:00'},
    { "id": 199, "entrada": "21:30:00", "salida": "00:00:00", "descanso": "00:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-05", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017", 'cantidad' : '00:00:00'},
    { "id": 200, "entrada": "01:00:00", "salida": "05:00:00", "descanso": "00:30:00", "fecha": "2018-10-08", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017", 'cantidad' : '00:00:00'},
    { "id": 201, "entrada": "03:00:00", "salida": "08:00:00", "descanso": "01:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-09", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017", 'cantidad' : '00:00:00'}
];
```

Comment: [JSON != Objeto Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: La pregunta fue editada, el mismo sentido de la pregunta ha cambiado. Creo que esto en injusto para los que ya han contestado.

Comment: Sólo edita tu respuesta y ya. Es nuevo colaborador, son obvias estas acciones.

Comment: Todos los comentario funcionan el problema era mio que estaba haciendo una asignación mal y por eso no me funcionó el principio. Gracias a todos los que me colaboraron.

Answer (score 7):

Hola prueba con esto:

```js
let json = { 
  "id": 197,
  "entrada": '07:00:00',
  "salida": '18:00:00',
  "descanso": '02:00:00',
  "fecha": '2018-10-02',
  "cantidad": '09:00',
  "proyecto": 'Contrato 343/2017' };
  
  json.nuevaClave = "nuevoValor";
  console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente con javascript, agregandolo de la siguiente manera:

```js
// asigno el json a una variable
var json = { "id": 197, "entrada": "07:00:00", "salida": "18:00:00", "descanso": 
  "02:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-02","cantidad": "09:00", "proyecto": 
  "Contrato 343/2017" };

console.log(json);
  
// modifico el json agregando un nuevo atributo como
// si fuera un objeto
json.nuevaClave = "nuevoValor";

console.log(json);
```

Comment: Esta muy bien tu ejemplo pero no me funciona, al hacer eso los datos se pierden y solo me toma el último valor cono un array.

Comment: Cómo lo estás ejecutando? Cómo es que te está tomando el último valor como un `array`?

Comment: Hago esto:  let datos = {'uno' : 1, 'dos' : 2, 'tres' : 3}; datos.cuatro = 4; Solo me imprime el 4.

Comment: Si eso lo ejecutás desde la consola, si, te muestra sólo el `4` pero si después de eso, hacés un `console.log(datos);` debería mostrarte todo el objeto con el `cuatro` incluido.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta de que si es un `array` o un `object` que son totalmente diferentes te dejo a continuación una gran diferencia:

```
var itemArray = {}, itemObject = [];
itemArray.id = 1;
itemArray.name = "albert";
itemObject.push(itemArray);
```

La variable `itemArray` como su nombre lo indica es un `array` y para agregar nuevos elementos es necesario llamar esta `variable` y agregar `.claveDelArray`. 
 Como se puede observar en el ejemplo agregamos `id` y `name` al `array` `itemArray`.
Para agregar nuevos elementos a un **objecto**-`(Object)` es necesario hacer uso del `método` [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push) y dentro del `método` pasar como parámetro el `item` que vamos agregar. 
 
Identificando tu problema veo que tienes un `array` y quieres agregar un nuevo `valor`, para hacer esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```js
var item = { "id": 197, "entrada": "07:00:00", "salida": "18:00:00", "descanso": 
  "02:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-02","cantidad": "09:00", "proyecto": 
  "Contrato 343/2017" }

  item.nuevoValor = "Nuevo Valor"
  console.log(item);
```

***Actualización*** 
Tienes que crear un `for` y recorrer cada `array` del objeto e ir agregando el `item` que necesitas en el `array`.

```js
let datos = [
        { "id": 197, "entrada": "07:00:00", "salida": "18:00:00", "descanso": "02:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-02", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
        { "id": 198, "entrada": "21:00:00", "salida": "23:00:00", "descanso": "00:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-03", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
        { "id": 199, "entrada": "21:30:00", "salida": "00:00:00", "descanso": "00:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-05", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
        { "id": 200, "entrada": "01:00:00", "salida": "05:00:00", "descanso": "00:30:00", "fecha": "2018-10-08", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
        { "id": 201, "entrada": "03:00:00", "salida": "08:00:00", "descanso": "01:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-09", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
        datos[i].cantidad = "00:00:00";
        console.log(datos);
    }
```

Comment: Entiendo la diferencia, pero al hacer lo de json.nuevoValor = "Nuevo velor" eso me reemplaza todo, solo me toma este último valor.

Comment: @DarwinZamora a que te refieres con que remplaza todo? no tienes la pregunta suficientemente clara, por favor editala.

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta si me puede ayudar te agradezco.

Comment: @DarwinZamora Espero que te haya servido mi actualización, quedo atento. Si esta respuesta ha sido útil por favor marca con la flecha arriba.

Comment: Tu respuesta me sirvió gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes trabajarlo con el método `push` del modo siguiente

```js
let json = [{ "id": 197, "entrada": "07:00:00", "salida": "18:00:00", "descanso": 
  "02:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-02"}]

console.log(json)

let nuevaData = json.push({"name": "SO en español", "cool": true})

console.log(json)
```

Aclaraciones

1. la variable json almacena la estructura json original
2. imprimo por primera vez la cadena json para ver su contenido
3. a la variable `nuevaData` guarda, que a la variable json le asigno dos nuevas claves con el método push, lo que hará que se guarden al final de la estructura json original
4. imprimo de nuevo el json y veré las nuevas clave/valor asignadas al final de la estructura

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que recorrer el arreglo y luego meter en cada JSON un nuevo nodo, en este caso "cantidad". Si quieres restar te recomendaría el plugin `moment`.

Te dejo un código funcionando

```js
let datos = [
    { "id": 197, "entrada": "07:00:00", "salida": "18:00:00", "descanso": "02:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-02", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
    { "id": 198, "entrada": "21:00:00", "salida": "23:00:00", "descanso": "00:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-03", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
    { "id": 199, "entrada": "21:30:00", "salida": "00:00:00", "descanso": "00:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-05", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
    { "id": 200, "entrada": "01:00:00", "salida": "05:00:00", "descanso": "00:30:00", "fecha": "2018-10-08", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" },
    { "id": 201, "entrada": "03:00:00", "salida": "08:00:00", "descanso": "01:00:00", "fecha": "2018-10-09", "proyecto": "Contrato 343/2017" }
];

datos.forEach( function( dato ){
  let entrada  = moment(dato.entrada, 'HH:mm:ss');
  let salida   = moment(dato.salida, 'HH:mm:ss');
  let cantidad = salida.diff(entrada, 'hours');
  dato.cantidad = cantidad;
});

console.log( datos );
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```