# ¿como puedo acceder a variable de JSON?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

de que forma podria acceder a esta variable de este json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: JSON != Objeto JS. Más detalles [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript/164944#164944)

Comment: Pon el código como texto, evita poner imagenes cuando se trate de código. Haz click en el botón editar para redactar correctamente tu pregunta

Comment: en este caso si copio y pego ese codigo no saldria de la misma forma porque es lo que se muestra en la response, se puede apreciar mejor en la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se ve podrías accederlo así: `response.Items[0].Registros[0].values[0]`, pero creo que antes deberías verificar que cada array tenga valores, porque de esta manera response, Registros o values puede venirte vacío y dar error en la aplicación.

Saludos.

Comment: de esta manera me sale un error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Registros' of undefined

Comment: Es verdad, me faltó la propiedad "Items".  Ya modifiqué la respuesta.

Comment: ahora lo que no puede leer es "Itmes" ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Items' of undefined

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que siempre devuelve la misma estructura JSON?

Comment: siii, es una api que yo hice en nodejs que obtiene unos datos de dynamodb una base de datos de amazon(aws), siempre me devuelve ese paquete de datos

Comment: puedes dar un console.log(response), para saber exactamente que es tu response? por que segun el error de arriba, response es undefined.
Y postear tambien el condigo completo dentro del subscribe.