# ¿Como obtener el valor de una propiedad en un arreglo de objetos JSON?

Tags: javascript, revisión-de-código

Tengo un arreglo de objetos y quiero obtener [152,153,154,155,156,157] que son los valores para la propiedad `intento` de cada objeto. Lo obtendría recorriendo con `for`, pero quiero saber si existe una función para hacerlo mas fácil.

```js
let arr= [{intento: 152, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 153, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 154, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 155, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 156, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 157, tipo: "intruso"}]
 
 let copy=[];
 for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
 copy.push(arr[i].intento);
 }
 console.log(copy);
```

Comment: para que la pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad puedes agregar el for que realizarías? y de ahi nosotros te proponemos una respuesta

Comment: @shadow listo he editado mi pregunta

Comment: Eso no es un *objeto JSON* [JSON!= objeto JS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay una manera más elegante de conseguirlo, pero creo que no es mucho más eficiente que el for. De todos modos te pongo la propuesta:

```js
let arr= [{intento: 152, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 153, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 154, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 155, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 156, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 157, tipo: "intruso"}]
 let resultado = arr.map(a => a.intento)
console.log(resultado);
```

Como ves en una sola línea obtienes el mismo resultado que el for, pero no se si es más rápido o no.

Comment: el detalle con `map` es que terminará siendo mas lento por que genera un arreglo nuevo con los valores tomados

Comment: Si, es justo lo que el necesita ya que quiere obtener un array con esos valores.

Comment: no leo en que parte diga que quiere un arreglo nuevo, solo dice que quiere obtener los valores de `intento` que es cosa aparte

Comment: Pues no sé, e interpretado esta línea así: "y quiero obtener [152,153,154,155,156,157]"

Comment: Y si alguien esta interesado en ver más sobre rendimiento --> https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS

Comment: Buen artículo !

Answer (score 3):

Si utilizas jQuery puedes hacerlo utilizando "map", sino creo que un ciclo for sería lo mejor.

```js
let arr = [
 {intento: 152, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 153, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 154, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 155, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 156, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 157, tipo: "intruso"}]
 
var res = $.map(arr, function( val, i ) { return val.intento; });

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: de hecho si utiliza solo javascript podria usar el map

Comment: Sólo con los navegadores que soportan ECMAScript 5, si tenés que hacer una aplicación web que utilice navegadores no tan actualizados te conviene usar jQuery o un ciclo for.

Comment: todos los [navegadores dan soporte](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) incluso desde Internet exporer 9

Comment: coloco otro [enlace de referencia](https://caniuse.com/#search=map)

Answer (score 2):

Realizalo a través de un `forEach()` de este modo

```
let data =[{intento: 152, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 153, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 154, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 155, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 156, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 157, tipo: "intruso"}]


data.forEach((element, index) => {
  console.log(element["intento"])
})
```

Simplemente necesitarás indicarle a la función que va por dentro 2 argumentos: `element` e `index` después en el console.log() le indicas que solo quieres el valor en `intento` de este modo `element["nombredelaclave"]`

A la larga `forEach` termina siendo mas rápido que `map` y de hecho este último te genera un arreglo nuevo partiendo del antes creado y creo eso no es lo que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

Y ya por poner otra opción... Pongo el `for of` de ES6

```js
let arr= [{intento: 152, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 153, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 154, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 155, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 156, tipo: "intruso"},
 {intento: 157, tipo: "intruso"}]
 
let copy = [];
 
for (let item of arr) {
   copy.push(item.intento);
}

console.log(copy);
```