# Convertir URL a Object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, array, object, objeto

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal (utilizando node.js) en el que necesito obtener **la ruta** de la solicitud **GET** por ejemplo `"/path/to/content"`, transformarlo en un Objeto y hacer que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  "path": {
    "to": {
      "content":[...]
     }
  }
}
```

Me parece que reemplazando con `split()` podría funcionar, he intentado de la siguiente manera:

```js
const button = document.getElementsByClassName("me");

for (var i=0; i < button.length; i++) {

  button[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var str = "/denyncrawford/files/img"; //path de la solicitud
    str = str.slice(1);
    var obj= str.split("/");
    document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += "  <pre>"+JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)+"</pre>"

    });

}
```

```css
p span {

  background-color: #f0e4da

}
```

```html
<p><b>PATH:</b><span>/denyncrawford/files/img</span></p>
<button class="me">Convertir</button>
```

Y esto me devuelve un *Array* que contiene las tres strings:

```
[
  "denyncrawford",
  "files",
  "img"
]
```

Como podría hacer para convertir el array en una ruta de objeto como en el primer ejemplo?:

```
{
  "denyncrawford": {
    "files": {
      "img":[...]
     }
  }
}
```

Porque utilizando `Object.assign()` resulta de la siguiente manera:

```
Object.assign({}, obj);
=> 
{
  0:"denyncrawford",
  1:"files",
  2:"img"
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!.

Comment: JSON es un formato, un objeto JS [es otra cosa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: Got it lo edito, gracias!! Algún aporte a la pregunta en si?

Comment: ¿Quieres acumular varias URL a un mismo objeto o quieres crear un objeto para cada URL?

Comment: Un objeto para cada ruta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las funciones de JSON solo funcionan con cadenas que siguen la estructura JSON, no entienden como convertir una ruta.  Tienes que construir el objeto tú mismo, `split` fue un buen punto inicial, aquí un ejemplo:

```js
var path = "/denyncrawford/files/img";

var obj = path
  .split('/')
  .filter(x => !!x)
  .reverse()
  .reduce((prev, current) => {
      return Object.keys(prev).length
        ? { [current]: prev }
        : { [current]: [] };
  }, {});
  
 console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Si, asumí que había que construirlo!! Muchas gracias por la solución!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una función recursiva que se encargue de hacer el trabajo:

```js
function urlToObject(url,value,target) {
  const param=url.shift();
  target= target || {};
  if (url.length === 0) {
    //caso base
    target[param]=value;
    
  } else {
    if (target[param] == null) {
      target[param]=urlToObject(url,value,{});
    } else {
      target[param]=urlToObject(url,value,target[param]);
    }
  }
  return target;
}

const URL='aplicacion/datos/img';
const URL2='aplicacion/datos/json';
let obj=urlToObject(URL.split('/'),true);

console.log(obj);
obj=urlToObject(URL2.split('/'),1,obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Esto te permitiría acumular datos en el mismo objeto padre (o no) dependiendo de si lo pasas como tercer parámetro. El segundo parámetro sería el valor final a asignar y el primer parámetro sería el resultado de hacer un split a la URL.