# Convertir un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos:

```
[
 {'nombre': u'0%', 'id': 1L},
 {'nombre': u'IVA 12%', 'id': 2L},
 {'nombre': u'IVA 14%', 'id': 3L},
 {'nombre': u'NO OBJETO DE IMPUESTO', 'id': 4L},
 {'nombre': u'EXCENTO DE IVA', 'id': 5L}
]
```

el cual deseo convertir a la siguiente forma:

```
{'1':'0%', '2':'IVA 12%'......}
```

Quizá alguna idea por donde comenzar de antemano muchas gracias.., La key, es el valor del ID, que retorno del Json.

Comment: [JSON no es Objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript), lo que muestras es un objeto, y falta agregar el codigo que intentastes

Comment: Quizá puedas intentar: const mutated = {}; array.forEach (i => { mutated [i.id] = i. nombre; });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediante [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) puedes transformar las entradas para retornar una nueva modificada.

**Ejemplo**

```js
const obj = [
 {'nombre': '0%', 'id': 1},
 {'nombre': 'IVA 12%', 'id': 2},
 {'nombre': 'IVA 14%', 'id': 3},
 {'nombre': 'NO OBJETO DE IMPUESTO', 'id': 4},
 {'nombre': 'EXCENTO DE IVA', 'id': 5 }
].map(o => ({
  [o.id]: o.nombre
}));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: genial... muy simple.. desconocia esa forma..

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
var lista = [
    {'nombre': '0%', 'id': '1L'},
    {'nombre': 'IVA 12%', 'id': '2L'},
    {'nombre': 'IVA 14%', 'id': '3L'},
    {'nombre': 'NO OBJETO DE IMPUESTO', 'id': '4L'},
    {'nombre': 'EXCENTO DE IVA', 'id': '5L'}
];

var final  = {};
for (var valor of lista) { // Iteramos por la lista
    valor['id'] = valor['id'].slice(0, -1); // Quitamos la 'L'
    final[valor['id']] = valor['nombre']; // Guardamos en { id: valor }
}
console.log(final); // {1: "0%", 2: "IVA 12%", 3: "IVA 14%", ... }
```

Fíjate que cambié el formato de la lista, ya que valores como `u'0%'` o `1L` estaban mal formateados. Aquí puedes ver el código en acción: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-5wulvb?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```
var obj ={
 {'nombre': u'0%', 'id': 1L},
 {'nombre': u'IVA 12%', 'id': 2L},
 {'nombre': u'IVA 14%', 'id': 3L},
 {'nombre': u'NO OBJETO DE IMPUESTO', 'id': 4L},
 {'nombre': u'EXCENTO DE IVA', 'id': 5L}
};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

El método JSON.stringify() convierte un valor dado en javascript a una cadena  JSON, opcionalmente reemplaza valores si es especificada la función de reemplazo, o si se especifican las propiedades mediante un array de reemplazo.

Comment: Por favor [edit] su respuesta y agregue una descripción clara de qué hace este código. La idea es publicar preguntas y respuestas de calidad.