# Como crear un elemento HTML con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy creando una lista a través de un `Objeto`, pero en el momento de añadirlo al elemento padre en el html con `appendChild` dice que se encuentra nulo.

```js
var pelis = [
    {
        Nombre: "El señor de los anillos",
        Genero: "Acción"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Regreso al Futuro",
        Genero: "Acción"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Los increibles 2",
        Genero: "Animación"
    },
];

var p = document.createElement("p");

for (i = 0; i <= pelis.length; i++){
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Nombre:" + pelis[i].Nombre + "|| Genero: " + pelis[i].Genero));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
        <h1>Lista de películas</h1>
```

Comment: [JSON no es Objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript/164944#164944)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente cambia el `<=` a `<`:

```js
var pelis = [
    {
        Nombre: "El señor de los anillos",
        Genero: "Acción"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Regreso al Futuro",
        Genero: "Acción"
    },
    {
        Nombre: "Los increibles 2",
        Genero: "Animación"
    },
];

var p = document.createElement("p");

for (i = 0; i < pelis.length; i++){
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Nombre:" + pelis[i].Nombre + "|| Genero: " + pelis[i].Genero));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="lista-pelis.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lista de películas</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```