# Como iterar un JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax

hago una petición ajax

```
 function obtener_datos_resul(id)
 {
     $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "./ajax/editar_resultados.php",
          data: "id="+id,
          success: function(datos){
            ......
            ......
        }
    });
}
```

Lo cual me retorna el siguiente JSON:

```
[{\"id\":\"494\",\"laboratorio_id\":\"137\",\"ordeblab\":\"291358\",\"parametro\":\"color\",\"resultado\":\"1\"},
{\"id\":\"495\",\"laboratorio_id\":\"137\",\"ordeblab\":\"291358\",\"parametro\":\"consistencia\",\"resultado\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"496\",\"laboratorio_id\":\"137\",\"ordeblab\":\"291358\",\"parametro\":\"directo\",\"resultado\":\"1\"}]"
```

Como itero esto en ajax, por ejemplo para obtener los ids?

Comment: que tal si haces un `JSON.parser(datos)` o agregas a tu ajax algo como `dataType:"json"`

Comment: te invito a leer [la Diferencia entre un JSON y un Objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript) alli mismo explica como hacer la conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De manera que recibes un string con formato JSON, necesitas utilizar [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) para formatearlo a un Objeto, después d ehacer esto utilizas un for e imprimes el valor de la clave que le indiques por notación de **.**.

```js
let objeto = "[{\"id\":\"494\",\"laboratorio_id\":\"137\",\"ordeblab\":\"291358\",\"parametro\":\"color\",\"resultado\":\"1\"}, {\"id\":\"495\",\"laboratorio_id\":\"137\",\"ordeblab\":\"291358\",\"parametro\":\"consistencia\",\"resultado\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"496\",\"laboratorio_id\":\"137\",\"ordeblab\":\"291358\",\"parametro\":\"directo\",\"resultado\":\"1\"}]";

let newboject = JSON.parse(objeto);

console.log(newboject);

for(let i = 0; i < newboject.length; i++){
  
    console.log(newboject[i].id);
    
}
```

Comment: Listo ya edite mi respuesta, me falto pasarle un JSON.parse(), nada más :B

Comment: Muy bien, funciona perfecto, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No hay de que compañero! :D