# Acceder a propiedades de un objeto JSON

Tags: jquery, json

Tengo este JSON

```
{
    "paises": [{
            "id_pais": "1",
            "pais": "Afganist\u00e1n"
        }, {
            "id_pais": "2",
            "pais": "Albania"
        }, {
            "id_pais": "3",
            "pais": "Alemania"
        }
    ]
}
```

Quiero acceder a las propiedades de cada objeto JSON con JQuery, como puedo hacer esto?

Tengo este código pero no funciona:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("localidad.json", function( data ) {


        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
           console.log("key: " + key + " val: " + val[1]["paises"]["id_pais"]);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: [JSON no es un Objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("localidad.json", function( data ) {


        $.each( data.paises, function( key, val ) {
           console.log("key: " + key + " val: " + val.id_pais + " " + val.pais);
        });
    });
});
```

Actualización filtro de impares:

```
$.getJSON("localidad.json", function( data ) {

    var impares = data.paises.filter(p => p.id_pais % 2 != 0);

        });
```

[array filter js](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

Comment: Me funciona, pero ahora tengo la siguiente duda si necesito pasar un parámetro para que solo me extraiga ciertos datos del json como por ejemplo los paises en los cuales el id_pais sea impar, se puede hacer esto??

Comment: Se puede, pero si quieres filtrar los datos te sugiero usar el método filter. Actualicé la respuesta para dejarte un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Y que tal si recorres el contenido de la propiedad países en el `each` el cual es un `array de objetos` y así en cada iteración accedes a las propiedades de cada objeto, así:

```js
var json = {
    "paises": [{
            "id_pais": "1",
            "pais": "Afganist\u00e1n"
        }, {
            "id_pais": "2",
            "pais": "Albania"
        }, {
            "id_pais": "3",
            "pais": "Alemania"
        }
    ]
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each(json.paises, function(key, val) {
    console.log(val.id_pais + ' - ' + val.pais)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```