# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un JSON de menor a mayor por su valor?

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo el siguiente JSON almacenado en una variable `a` en Javascript

```
{
   "cajas":0.3,
   "comida": 0.4,
   "cosas":3.4
}
```

Como puedo ordenarlo de mayor a menor para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
{
   "cosas":3.4
   "comida": 0.4,
   "cajas":0.3,
}
```

Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Qué es lo que haz intentado? No sería de ayuda resolver el problema sin antes muestres un avance.

Comment: Hola. He intanto usar el metodo sort() de Javascript. El problema es que revisando necesito que la clave sea la misma, por ejemplo `{ objeto:3.4, objeto:0.4, objeto:0.3}` para poderlo ordenar. Pero mis claves son diferentes entonces estoy algo perdido.

Comment: Ya te respondí, espero te sirva.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el tipo de la la variable `a`, `string` u `object`?

Comment: [JSON != objeto Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entonces construye un array de objetos donde tenga clave y valor, no se altera ningún dato solamente la forma en obtener su valor, por ejemplo.

```js
var objeto = [
   {"nombre":"cajas", "valor": 0.3},
   {"nombre": "comida", "valor": 0.4},
   {"nombre": "cosas", "valor": 3.4}
];

var order = objeto.sort(function(a, b){ 
        
          if (a.valor > b.valor) {
          return -1;

          }
        
    });
    
    console.log(order);
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! El problema es que el JSON viene de una API entonces no puedo modificarla. Más que nada por eso estoy atorado.

Comment: @IsaacAlejandro disculpe la molestia , su código me vino como anillo al dedo , para agregar una funcionalidad en Javascript, pero quisiera preguntarle para que utiliza el return -1, es decir ya se que es necesario porque ordena de mayor a menor, pero no entiendo el porque ponerlo de esa forma, se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: @RodrigoA.Moreno puedes obtener más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort).