# Ordenar Objeto de Angular (Keyvalue)

Tags: angular

Necesito ordenar mi JSON por id ascendentemente, por la consola me lo saca ordenado, pero a la hora de pintarlo me lo despinta, sabéis como puedo hacerlo?

**EDITO**

> Ya se de donde viene el error y por que, pero no se solucionarlo a ver
>   si alguien puede hecharme una mano, el error viene del `keyvalue` lo
>   está ordenando correctamente pero cuando llega al número 10 lo coge
>   como si fuese un 1 entonces lo pone debajo del 1 cuando llega el 11 lo
>   pone en tercera posición porque lo coge como otro 1 y así
>   sucesivamente...

```
<ng-template #bloqueTemplate let-bloque='obj'>
    <mat-expansion-panel class="bloque">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>{{bloque.titulo}}</mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div *ngFor="let pregunta of bloque.preguntas | keyvalue">
        Hola
        {{ bloque.id}}
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="preguntaTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{obj:pregunta.value, id: bloque.id}">
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
    <div>
        <canvas id="{{bloque.id}}">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

No se si puede que esté en esta parte de código

```
            <div *ngFor="let item of cuestionario.content | keyvalue">
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="isPregunta(item.value) ? preguntaTemplate : bloqueTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{obj:item.value, id: isPregunta(item.value) ? 0 : item.value.id}">
            </ng-container>
        </div>
```

cuestionario.content

```
   initFormControl() {
    for(var index in this.cuestionario.content) {
      var item = this.cuestionario.content[index];

      if(this.isPregunta(item)) {
        this.crearFormControls(item, 0);
      } else {
        for(var preg of item.preguntas) {
          this.crearFormControls(preg, item.id);
        }
      }
    }

    this.done = true;
    this.getGraphsData()
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [JSON != Objeto en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que hay en `cuestionario.content`? Si es un array puedes ordenarlo fácilmente con el método `sort`

Comment: Por supuesto que puedo @PabloLozano                                             `initFormControl() {
    for(var index in this.cuestionario.content) {
      var item = this.cuestionario.content[index];

      if(this.isPregunta(item)) {
        this.crearFormControls(item, 0);
      } else {
        for(var preg of item.preguntas) {
          this.crearFormControls(preg, item.id);
        }
      }
    }

    this.done = true;

    this.getGraphsData()
  }`

Comment: Por favor, usa [edit] para añadir datos a la pregunta. De todos modos me refiero a los datos que hay en la variable, no al código en sí.

Comment: @PabloLozano te refieres a eso?

Comment: No me cuadra con el código: si cada entrada es un item, no hay campo `value`. Hay id, titulo, visibleCliente... y no parece ser un array, sino un objeto con propiedades con clave numérica

Comment: Si, es un poco raro @PabloLozano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucione de esta manera.

Como mi objeto ya estaba ordenado lo que hice fue decirle al keyvalue que no haga nada básicamente por lo que cree una función retornando 0 y la llame desde el keyvalue

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of cuestionario.content | keyvalue : returnZero">
     <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="isPregunta(item.value) ? preguntaTemplate : bloqueTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{obj:item.value, id: isPregunta(item.value) ? 1 : item.value.id}">
     </ng-container>
 </div>
```

Y en la función

```
  returnZero() {
    return 0
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

No es mejor usar el pipe siguiente??

```
*ngFor="let item of items| orderBy:fieldName"
```

Espero que te ayude

Comment: En lugar de preguntar yo agregaría una explicación de cómo esto soluciona el problema del OP

Comment: Lo que no me entra en la cabeza es si en el objeto me lo muestra ordenado por que a la hora de pintarlo, lo pinta desordenado

Comment: Lo suyo es utilizar un pipe: te dejo el ejemplo en: https://stackblitz.com/edit/sort-with-pipe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: @Miguel Ángel Martín : Te he actualizado y parametrizado el pipe para que así puedas ordenar la lista por el campo que desees: https://stackblitz.com/edit/sort-with-pipe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Luiggi me tira el siguiente error `The pipe 'sort' could not be found ("expansion-panel-header>{{bloque.titulo}}</mat-expansion-panel-header>`

Comment: Añadí el código abajo, míralo!

Answer (score 0):

te agrego el código.

1. Generamos un pipe como este:

```typescript
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "sort"
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array: Array<any>, args: string): Array<any> {
        return array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            if (a[args] < b[args]) {
                return -1;
            } else if (a[args] > b[args]) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2. Añadimos el Pipe al app.module o tu módulo específico

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { SortPipe } from './sort.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, SortPipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. En el componente asumimos que tenmos una lista como esta:

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  list:any[] = [
    {id:2,name:'d'},
    {id:5,name:'a'},
    {id:4,name:'b'},
    {id:1,name:'a'},
    {id:3,name:'z'},
    {id:6,name:'c'},
  ]
}
```

4. Solo nos queda añadir el pipe a nuestro ngfor:

```
   <label>lista ordenada Sort</label>
    <div *ngFor="let item of list | sort: 'id'">{{item.id}}</div>
```

Cualquier duda lo miramos

Comment: No me hace nada, no me tira error pero tampoco me ordena

Comment: Me ha tirado el siguiente error al ponerlo en otro ngFor `array.sort is not a function`

Comment: Si quito el Keyvalue del ngFor no me muestra nada, supongo que pueden venir x ahí los tiros

Answer (score -1):

Un ejemplo con Javascript sería así:

```
let items = [
  { name: 'Edward', id: 4},
  { name: 'Sharpe', id: 5},
  { name: 'And', id: 3},
  { name: 'The', id: 2},
  { name: 'Magnetic', id: 1},
  { name: 'Zeros', id: 10 }
];

items.sort((a,b) => Number(a.id) - Number(b.id));
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```
[
  { name: 'Magnetic', id: 1},
  { name: 'The', id: 2},
  { name: 'And', id: 3},
  { name: 'Edward', id: 4},
  { name: 'Sharpe', id: 5},
  { name: 'Zeros', id: 10 }
]
```