# Error al parsear JSON (SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 13033289)

Tags: json, nodejs

Tengo esta cuestión: necesito leer un archivo `JSON` y *parsearlo*, no tuve problema de hacerlo con archivos chicos, pero con uno más extenso me provocó el error mencionado.

Este es mi código:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var contents = fs.readFileSync(`./myjsonfile.json`, `utf-8`)

var jsonArray = JSON.parse(contents)
```

Parte del archivo:

```
[
    {
        "calle" : 1,
        "nombrecalle" : "NOMBRE DE CALLE",
        "keyx" : 1
    },
    {
        "calle" : 2,
        "nombrecalle" : "NOMBRE DE CALLE",
        "keyx" : 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Alguna posibilidad de ver el contenido del archivo?

Comment: Ya lo agregué.. @Alfabravo

Comment: Me late que el "NOMBRE DE CALLE" contiene apóstrofes

Comment: Puede ser que las propíedades en esa posicion esten mal, algún caracter especial, no veo otro problema.

Comment: Aparte de eso, el metodo JSON.parse() lo que hace es convertir un string a JSON y lo que tu ya tienes es un JSON.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse

Comment: No puedes parsear un archivo .JSON, por que ya esta en ese formato.

Comment: En caso de tener caracteres especiales, alguna solución?@CesarArmando

Comment: Para los valores especiales  (caracteres), deben de estar "escapados" , lo que tendiras que hacer o al menos es lo que se me ocurre ahora, seria crear una expresion regular (regex) que te ayude a encontrar esos caracteres.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274204/json-parse-with-escape-characters

Comment: estas cargando un Objeto no un JSON por ello el error, no te es necesario hacer el parser

Comment: puedes ver mas al respecto en [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript]

Comment: Mario, revisa mi respuesta que te deje. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uno de los problemas puede ser el siguiente:

Para la salida de un `JSON` este debe estar envuelto en un `{}` y un array `[]` no puede convertirse directamente a formato `JSON`.

Prueba con lo siguiente, envolviendo tu array en llaves `{}`

```
{
    [
        {
            "calle" : 1,
            "nombrecalle" : "NOMBRE DE CALLE",
            "keyx" : 1
        },
        {
            "calle" : 2,
            "nombrecalle" : "NOMBRE DE CALLE",
            "keyx" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Eso si es un `JSON` y se puede parsear sin problemas. Me cuentas como te va con eso. Saludos !.