# Como editar información de un JSON dentro de un Array en javascript/typescript (NativeScript) sin usar foreach

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, nativescript

Como bien el título lo dice, busco editar un JSON que se encuentra dentro de un Array con "N" cantidad elementos, pero busco realizarlo a través de una función la cual recibirá el `id` del valor a editar, y busco que sea de la manera más sencilla posible evitando usar un foreach.
Estoy realizando una app en Nativescript con Angular.

```
var data = [
  {id:1, nombre:"nombre1", editable:true},
  {id:2, nombre:"nombre2", editable: false},
  {id:3, nombre:"nombre3", editable: false},
  {id:4, nombre:"nombre4", editable: false},
  {id:5, nombre:"nombre5", editable: false}
]
```

Por ello me he planteado:

- Usar la propiedad [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) para buscar por el **id** a editar.
- Usar el [indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) para obtener el indice de ese valor obtenido.
- Usar la propiedad [splice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) para generar la edición

> Ejemplo:
>
> Cambiar el estado del `id:2` de `editable: false` a `editable: true`

Se que suena sencillo, pero no termino de visualizar como ejecutar este código ya que no logro obtener el `ìndexOf` del valor filtrado. Si pueden ayudarme a diseñar esta función, se los agradeceré enormemente.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas directamente .find()? `const encontrado = data.find(i => i.id === 2)` y una vez q lo tienes: `encontrado.editable = true`

Comment: [JSON  no es Objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cuál-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si solo hay un elemento con el ID que buscas, mejor usar la función [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) en lugar de [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter).

`find()` te devuelve el primer elemento que encaje con lo que le digas, pero `filter()` te busca todas y te devuelve un array con esos. Por lo tanto, `find()` será más eficiente porque parará cuando encuentre el elemento (si no lo encuentra devuelve `undefined`), filter siempre acabará recorriendo todo el array.

Ejemplo con `find()`:

```js
var data = [
  {id:1, nombre: "nombre1", editable: true},
  {id:2, nombre: "nombre2", editable: false},
  {id:3, nombre: "nombre3", editable: false}
]

var elementoAEditar = data.find(elemento => elemento.id === 2);

// Para asegurar que encuentra el elemento, ponemos este if. Si no lo encuentra no entrará en el if.
if (elementoAEditar) {
    elementoAEditar.editable = true;
}

// Ahora data[1].editable (el de ID 2) será igual a true.
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

puedes usar la función **findIndex()** de JavaScript. Te dejo un codigo a continucación para ver si es lo que necesitas:

```js
var data = [{id:1, nombre:"nombre1", editable:true},
{id:2, nombre:"nombre2", editable: false},
{id:3, nombre:"nombre3", editable: false},
{id:4, nombre:"nombre4", editable: false},
{id:5, nombre:"nombre5", editable: false}]

var index = data.findIndex(data => data.id==2);

console.log(index);

data[index].editable = true;

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puede ser algo asi:

```js
var data = [
  {id:1, nombre:"nombre1", editable:true},
  {id:2, nombre:"nombre2", editable: false},
  {id:3, nombre:"nombre3", editable: false},
  {id:4, nombre:"nombre4", editable: false},
  {id:5, nombre:"nombre5", editable: false}
]

 data.find( d => d.id == 2 ).editable = true

console.log(data)
```

Este código esta simplificado. Si quieres comprobar que de verdad exista el elemento podrías usar algo así:

```js
var data = [
  {id:1, nombre:"nombre1", editable:true},
  {id:2, nombre:"nombre2", editable: false},
  {id:3, nombre:"nombre3", editable: false},
  {id:4, nombre:"nombre4", editable: false},
  {id:5, nombre:"nombre5", editable: false}
]

 var comprobar = data.find( d => d.id == 2 )

if( comprobar ){ 
  comprobar.editable = true
  console.log(data)
} 
else {
  console.log('No existe el id')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Todas las funciones que mencionas, y otras que se podrían usar, iteran sobre el array como el `foreach` o un `for`. Lo único que mejoraría significativamente la performance es no seguir iterando si encuentra una coincidencia.

Manualmente se lograría haciendo `for` y `break`, y en cuanto a las funciones nativas que harían el *break*:
`some()` retorna `true` o `false` si encuentra o no el elemento, pero si necesitas el elemento coincidente lo mejor en mi criterio es usar `find()` o `findIndex()`. 
El primero devuelve el elemento y el segundo el indice.
Si necesitas modificar el valor que buscas, lo mejor es usar `findIndex()`.

```js
var data = [
  {id:1, nombre:"nombre1", editable:true},
  {id:2, nombre:"nombre2", editable: false},
  {id:3, nombre:"nombre3", editable: false},
  {id:4, nombre:"nombre4", editable: false},
  {id:5, nombre:"nombre5", editable: false}
];

data[data.findIndex(e=>e.id === 4)].nombre = "nuevo nombre 4";

console.log(data);
```

Este es solo un ejémplo básico de funcionamiento, porque como bien indica @JackNavaRow en este ejemplo en particular si el inidice no existe va a arrojar error, y si la propiedad `nombre` no existe, también va a arrojar error. Estoy asumiendo que el indice siempre va a existir y la propiedad también. Si este no fuera el caso, hay que considerar esos recaudos.

Comment: y si el index no existe , te va a dar un error!

Comment: @JackNavaRow si, claro, en este ejemplo tiraría error. Tampoco lo hice dinámico. Estoy asumiendo que los ids existen si o si.