# ¿Como crear un array json a partir de un foreach que acumule objetos?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

Tengo la siguiente función donde itera el grupo de objetos **tags** para poder consultar un dato de cada objeto con una librería,

```
    //Esta es la lista a iterar

var tags = ["Contador_Turno", "Contador_Pedido", "Paquetes", "Tarimas"]

readTag(plc) {
    const json = [];
    this.tags.forEach(tag => {
       //Aqui se itera cada tag (por ejemplo "Contador_Turno" y se utiliza una libreria para consultar el valor de cada tag)
        plc.read(`${tag}`).then(data => {
            //Aqui es donde trato de asignar los valores correspondientes de cada tag para formar un array json 
            json.push(tag, data)
            console.log(json)
        })
    });
}
```

la salida de esa función en consola es la siguiente:

```
[ 'Contador_Pedido', 66 ]
[ 'Contador_Pedido', 66, 'Paquetes', 1 ]
[ 'Contador_Pedido', 66, 'Paquetes', 1, 'Contador_Turno', 66 ]
[
  'Contador_Pedido',
  66,
  'Paquetes',
  1,
  'Contador_Turno',
  66,
  'Tarimas',
  0
]
```

Estoy tratando de que el json quede de la siguiente manera que cada **tag** quede con su valor correspondiente

```
[{'Contador_Pedido': 66, 'Paquetes': 1, 'Contador_Turno': 66, 'Tarimas': 0}]
```

les agradeceria que me ayudaran a ver donde esta el error

Comment: Puedes poner tu dataset?

Comment: [JSON !== Objeto Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: Quieres un array con un único objeto?

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que debería contener cada elemento de this.tags? Me da la sensación que estás confundiendo la salida que tú quieres (cadena json) con la que te muestra el console.log

Comment: He añadido cambios si pueden checarlos por favor

Comment: Podes usar map para eso en vez de foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear objetos dentro de un arreglo sería

```
readTag(plc) {
    const json = [];
    this.tags.forEach(tag => {
        plc.read(`${tag}`).then(data => {
            json.push({ tag: data })
            console.log(json)
        })
    });
}
```

Sólo te faltaba agregar los símbolos de apertura y cierre propios de un objeto.

Nos comentas si te sirvió

Comment: Me arroja la salida en consola asi:  [ { tag: 66 } ]
[ { tag: 66 }, { tag: 66 } ]
[ { tag: 66 }, { tag: 66 }, { tag: 1 } ]
[ { tag: 66 }, { tag: 66 }, { tag: 1 }, { tag: 0 } ]

Comment: Puedes incluir el arreglo completo?

Comment: Este es mi arreglo completo, ["Contador_Turno", "Contador_Pedido", "Paquetes", "Tarimas"] es el que itero para consultar el dato de cada uno de los objetos

Comment: @SaulEspinoza data es un arreglo también?

Comment: data es el dato que se obtiene de un objeto iterado por ejemplo "Contador_Pedido": 60 la idea es que el data se le asigne a cada objeto iterado y formen un array json

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar map en vez de foreach:

```
const json = [];
json = this.tags.map(tag => {
    plc.read(`${tag}`).then(data => {
        return(tag,data)
        console.log(json)
    })
});
```

Comment: Setia bueno que expliques las ventajas y la razón de por qué utilizar `map()`