# Tomar campos de una cadena con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
 {"sub":"{\"nombre\":\"HORACIO\",\"fechaNacimiento\":4444444,\"apellido\":\"GONZALEZ\",\"edad\":\"34\",\"nivel\":\"3\"}","iss":"CENTRO","exp":235}
```

Quiero quedarme con los valores de los campos nombre y apellido, es decir, HORACIO y GONZALEZ.

Como puedo realizarlo con JavaScript?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido por favor considera leer [ask]

Comment: Es una cadena o un json?

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, esa es exactamente la cadena o le falta algunos caracteres?.

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser un `json` (mal armado). Te dejo un jsfiddle para que veas como utilizar el `JSON.parse` https://jsfiddle.net/a40vjsh6/

Comment: Puedes ver la documentación de [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse). Con eso ya puedes trabajar si tu cadena está en formato JSON. Saludos

Comment: @gbianchi un JSON es una cadena

Comment: @PabloLozano si si.. queria saber si OP lo sabia...

Answer (score 6):

Lo que tienes es una cadena de un texto en JSON. Puedes convertirlo a JSON:

`var objeto = JSON.parse(cadena)`

Luego puedes acceder a las propiedades del JSON

`var nombre = objeto.sub.nombre;`

Comment: [JSON !== Objeto Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

ps la cadena es `JSON` y el valor de `sub` es `texto` entonces convertimos a `JSON` dicho valor para poder obtener los valores

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = {"sub":"{\"nombre\":\"HORACIO\",\"fechaNacimiento\":4444444,\"apellido\":\"GONZALEZ\",\"edad\":\"34\",\"nivel\":\"3\"}","iss":"CENTRO","exp":235};
  var sub = JSON.parse(data.sub);
  console.log(sub);
  $("#nombre").html(sub.nombre+" "+sub.apellido);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nombre"></div>
```