# Filtrar por ID elementos de un Objeto Con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

quiero filtrar elementos de un Json por id pero me aparece error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al momento de filtrar por nombre no me aparece ningún error

```js
class Busqueda{
    
    constructor(){
        const url = "https://servexusinc.com/api/Model/getTestData"
        fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

       
        this.json = data
        this.jsonBK = this.json
        this.onInit();
    })
    }
    onInit(){
        let cuerpo = document.getElementById("cuerpo");
        while(cuerpo.rows.length > 0){
            cuerpo.deleteRow(0);
        }
        this.json.forEach(persona => {
            let fila = cuerpo.insertRow(cuerpo.rows.length);
            fila.insertCell(0).innerHTML = persona.Id;
            fila.insertCell(1).innerHTML = persona.Name;
            fila.insertCell(2).innerHTML = persona.Description;
            fila.insertCell(3).innerHTML = persona.PartNumber;
            fila.insertCell(4).innerHTML = persona.LowFile;
            fila.insertCell(5).innerHTML = persona.Price;
            fila.insertCell(6).innerHTML = persona.ImgSrc;
            fila.insertCell(7).innerHTML = persona.Available;
            fila.insertCell(8).innerHTML = persona.Layers;
            fila.insertCell(9).innerHTML = persona.Options;
            fila.insertCell(10).innerHTML = persona.DefaultLayers;
            fila.insertCell(11).innerHTML = persona.MoveToZeroLayers;
            fila.insertCell(12).innerHTML = persona.Filters;
        })
    }
    buscar(id){
        let busqueda = document.getElementById(id).value;
        this.json = this.jsonBK;
        this.json = this.json.filter(persona => {
             return persona.Id.indexOf(busqueda) > -1;
             
           
        })
        this.onInit();
    }
}
let busqueda = new Busqueda();
let form = document.getElementById("busquedaForm");
form.addEventListener('submit', ()=>{
    busqueda.buscar('valor');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Api Fetch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="javascript:void(0);" id="busquedaForm"><input type="text" id="valor"><button>Enviar</button></form>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>ImgSrc</th>
                    <th>Available</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="cuerpo"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradeazco su ayuda, no se si tengo que convertir en entero al momento de realizar el filtro en **buscar()**

Comment: [JSON=! Objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: el metodo ```indexOf``` es para tipo string asi que parsea el numero primero

Comment: En que momento lo parseo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Id` es un entero, debe ser convertido antes a `string`

p.ej:

`String(persona.Id).indexOf(busqueda) > -1;`

Comment: Si respondio mis dudas!