# Crear un array de un submenu en una UL

Tags: javascript, html5

como les van? estoy intentando crear un submenu a partir de un JSON y quisiera saber si la forma que escribi estaba encaminado a ser correcto. Desde ya, muchas gracias !

```
<li id="arrayjson"> </li>


    var json = {
    submenu:[
        {titulo: 'Ropa', url: '/ropa.html'},
        {titulo: 'Electronica', url: '/electronica.html'},
        {titulo: 'Higiene', url: '/higiene.html'},
        {titulo: 'Alimentos', url: '/alimentos.html'},
        {titulo: 'Otros', url: '/otros.html'}
    ]
};

var claseul = document.getElementById('arrayjson');

document.write("<ul>");

json.submenu.forEach((titulo, url)=>{
    document.write(`<li><a href${url}>${titulo}</a></li>`);
}); 


document.write("</ul>");
```

Gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varios detalles:

- No te recomiendo usar `document.write()`. El por qué es sencillo: doument write borrará todo el documento (tu HTML) para iniciar uno nuevo desde cero. Puesto que lo normal es querer **editar** el documento actual, te aconsejo aprender a usar el DOM.
- [JSON != Objeto Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript). Puede parecer una tontería, pero cuando antes aprendas esto, mejor.

```js
Te pongo un ejemplo basado en tu código:

let menu = {
  submenu:[
        {titulo: 'Ropa', url: '/ropa.html'},
        {titulo: 'Electronica', url: '/electronica.html'},
        {titulo: 'Higiene', url: '/higiene.html'},
        {titulo: 'Alimentos', url: '/alimentos.html'},
        {titulo: 'Otros', url: '/otros.html'}
  ]
};

const list = document.querySelector('#menu');

menu.submenu.forEach(element => {
  const li = document.createElement('li'); //creamos un elemento de la lista
  const link = document.createElement('a');// creamos un enlace
  link.href = element.url;
  link.innerHTML = element.titulo;

  li.appendChild(link); //metemos el enlace en el elemento
  list.appendChild(li); //metemos el elemento en la lista
});
```

```html
<ul id="menu"></ul>
```

Comment: FUNCIONO !!!! gracias, mil gracias !

Comment: @axesthetic no olvides marcar la respuesta como valida si te sirvió.

Comment: Listo ! mil gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Tu idea esta buena, pero no es funcional del todo porque como sabes los JSON tienen una estructura de Llave y valor, por lo que el `forEach` que estas utilizando aun no llegas a los indices de cada uno. Te dejo un ejemplo de como podria funcionarte.

```js
var json = {
    submenu:[
        {titulo: 'Ropa', url: '/ropa.html'},
        {titulo: 'Electronica', url: '/electronica.html'},
        {titulo: 'Higiene', url: '/higiene.html'},
        {titulo: 'Alimentos', url: '/alimentos.html'},
        {titulo: 'Otros', url: '/otros.html'}
    ]
};

var claseul = document.getElementById('arrayjson');
var i;
document.write("<ul>");
for (i in json.submenu) {
  document.write(`<li><a href="${json.submenu[i].url}">${json.submenu[i].titulo}</a></li>`);
}


document.write("</ul>");
```

```html
<div id="arrayjson"></div>
```

Comment: Funciono ! pero me crea el ul afuera del contenedor que queria hacer

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pon el contenedor en donde lo necesitas

Comment: como hago para editar la pregunta? solo me deja eliminarla