# Mostrar los elementos de un objeto JSON en HTML solo muestra el ultimo elemento

Tags: javascript, html

Hola amigos mi problema es que al intentar mostrar los datos contenidos en un objeto se muestra por pantalla solo el ultimo elemento de la lista, lo curioso es que cuando hago uso del console.log o de document.write si se muestran todos los elementos de la lista, e guardado la información en una variable y nada, lo convertí en una cadena de texto y no funciono, quisiera que me proporcionaran su ayuda por favor de ante mano muchisimas gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$(".btnVerVenta").click(function(){
  var idVenta = $(this).attr("idVenta");
  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append("idVenta", idVenta);
  $.ajax({
    url:"ajax/ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respuesta){
  var CadenaJson = respuesta['articulos'];
  var articulosObjeto = JSON.parse(CadenaJson);
  // // $("#agruparArticulos").val(JSON.stringify(agruparArticulos));
       for (var i = 0; i < articulosObjeto.length; i++) {
         $(".prueba").html(
        '<p><b>'+articulosObjeto[i]["descripcion"]+'</b></p>'+
        '<br/>')
        console.log(articulosObjeto[i]["descripcion"]);
    }

    }
  })
})
```

Comment: [JSON != Objeto Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: En el bucle, en vez de `$(".prueba").html(...)` tendrías que usar `append()`, pues `html()` te cambiará el contenido, mientras que `append` te lo irá agregando a lo que ya hay. De todos modos, no conviene nunca modificar el DOM dentro de bucles, es mejor recoger todo en una variable dentro del bucle y luego fuera de él lo colocas al elemento deseado, de ese modo, modificas el DOM una sola vez, no `N` veces. Si el bucle tiene 1000 elementos modificas el DOM 1000 veces, y si tiene un millón de elementos, pues eso, modificas el DOM 1 millón de veces. Se llama *optimizar* el código.

Comment: Si me funciona ya entiendo lo que me dices muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo se muestra uno porque estas sobre escribiendo en cada ciclo el valor del `$(".prueba").html)`, lo que debes hacer es tomar el valor existente y agregarle el valor adicional de esta manera

```
   for (var i = 0; i < articulosObjeto.length; i++) {
     $(".prueba").append(
    '<p><b>'+articulosObjeto[i]["descripcion"]+'</b></p>'+
    '<br/>')
   }
```

Comment: Gracias Dios me le pague si era eso

Comment: Aceptala como respuesta, que viene a ser lo mismo! UwU

Comment: listo aceptada me costo mucho conseguir el botón jejeje también vote pero como es mi primera pregunta no vale mucho mi voto nuevamente gracias