# Leer fichero .txt en json

Tags: javascript, json

mi problema es que tengo un fichero compuesto por nombres en en cada linea, tal que asi:

```
Juan
Ramon
Pedro
Jose
```

pues bien lo que tengo que hacer es leer cada nombre y añadirlo a un objeto json. Por el momento tengo esto:

```
var express = require('express');
const fs = require("fs");
var app = express();

var alumnos
fs.readFile('alumnos.txt', (err, data) => { 
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.toString) 

})
```

El problema es que ese data.tostring me devuelve los valores correctos (Juan,Ramon,...) pero no se como separarlos por lineas y añadirlos a la variable alumnos con la clave "nombre". Es necesario usar File System

Muchas gracias

Comment: [JSON !== Objeto javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: Cada línea del archivo `alumnos.txt`, ¿Qué representa? Por otro lado, `alumnos`, ¿Es un array?

Comment: Cada linea es un nombre de una persona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes todo el fichero en un string, puedes separar las líneas con `split`:

```js
const fichero = `
Juan
Ramon
Pedro
Jose
`;



//simulando NodeJs
function readFile(fileName,func) {
  func(undefined,fichero);
}


readFile('alumnos.txt', (err, data) => { 
  if (err) throw err;
  let lineas = data.split('\n');
  lineas = lineas.filter(linea => linea); //quitamos las líneas de 0 caracteres
  console.log('Líneas encontradas:', lineas.length);
  lineas.forEach((linea, i) => console.log(`La línea ${i} es ${linea}`));

});
```

Comment: Pero es que yo no tengo la variable fichero, es un documento .txt donde estan los nombres

Comment: Lo he puesto así para que sea ejecutable en la página, pero te añado el código para leer

Comment: pero yo no puedo hacer fichero.split('\n'); si no tengo la variable fichero

Comment: Mira la edición que he hecho

Comment: la respuesta es "TypeError: data.split is not a function"

Comment: modifica la llamada a la función readFile: `readFile('alumnos.txt','utf8',(err,data) => ...`