# se puede ordenar un arreglo que contiene otros arreglos json

Tags: javascript, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

tengo el siguiente ejemplo un arreglo con otros arreglos dentro el metodo sort funciona muy bien cuando es un simple arreglo con los json , pero en este caso que estaría faltando?

```
const input = [
    [{id: 1, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"}],
    [{id: 2, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"}],
    [{id: 3, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"}],
    [{id: 4, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"}]
];

let sortedInput = input.slice().sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);
console.log(sortedInput);
```

Comment: No se que es lo que pretendes hacer y a lo mejor lo necesitas así, pero sobran los `[]` de cada array. `{id: 1, keyOne: "valueOne", keyTwo: "valueTwo"}`. Al quitarlos, ordena de forma descendente, como lo tienes programado.

Comment: así es también lo note, solo que así es como logre obtener unos valores que recibo en respuesta ajax con un cilco for , seguire revisando para ver si los puedo obtener simple, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Resulta que los elementos de `input` son de tipo `array`, lo que te falta especificar en tu función de ordenamiento (`sort`), es el índice del elemento sobre el cual vas a realizar el ordenamiento. En el ejemplo que pones en tu pregunta el índice sería `0`. Por ejemplo: `sort((a, b) => b[0].id - a[0].id);`.

Comment: [JSON `!==` Objeto Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)