# ¿Cómo separar un JSON en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios

Tengo problemas al intentar separar un JSON en diferentes valores, ¿cómo puedo separar el json para guardarlos en variables y poder mostrarlos en un input html? Estoy utilizando axios.

este el es json que obtengo;

```
    obtenerUsuario:
       apell_USUARIO: "pumbaa"
       contra_USUARIO: "1234"
       fec_REG_USUARIO: "2020-10-22T11:38:14.383"
       id_USUARIO: 2
       nom_USUARIO: "timon"
       usu_USUARIO: "local2"
```

este el el jquery axios, la data se almacena en rpta y es ahí donde quiero separarla

```
function fnObtener(){
var id= $('#txtId').val();
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/usu/obtenerUsuario', {
"ID_USUARIO": id
}, {
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
}, {
}).then((response) => {
fnRespuestaObtener(response.data);
})
}

function fnRespuestaObtener(rpta){

  var id= $('#txtId').val();
  var nombre=$('#txtNombres').val();
  var apellido=$('#txtApellidos').val();
  var usuario=$('#txtUsuario').val();
  var contrasea=$('#txtContrasena').val();

  if(id=="ID_USUARIO"){
    nombre.text=nom_USUARIO;
    apellido.text=apell_USUARIO;
    usuario.text=usu_USUARIO;
    contrasea.text=contra_USUARIO;
  }
}
```

Comment: fijate como responde un `console.log(response.data)` dependiendo de eso, puedes ver como usar el `json`, si puedes colocalo dentro de la pregunta. Suponiendo que la primera parte del codigo sea la respuesta, te bastaría cambiar la forma como la usas dentro de tu funcion a por ejemplo `nombre.text=rpta.nom_USUARIO;`

Comment: [JSON != JS Object](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: @FelipeUrcia pongo nombre.text=rpta.nom_USUARIO; pero me sale en el nombre =  undefined

Comment: Tienes un problema, no sólo con la forma en que manejas la respuesta, sino en como pretendes asignarla. `$('#identif').val()` devuelve el valor del elemento identificado por `#identif`. Por lo tanto las variables a las que pretendes asignarle este valor serán de tipo `String` o `Array` o serán `undefined`. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te entiendo bien, con *separar el json para guardarlo en variables* te refieres a hacer una [destructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment) de objetos JSON.

Cuándo haces el `post` con Axios y obtienes como respuesta un objeto, puedes destructurarlo para acceder a sus propiedades.

Si el objeto que obtienes consiste en:

```
obtenerUsuario:
   apell_USUARIO: "pumbaa"
   contra_USUARIO: "1234"
   fec_REG_USUARIO: "2020-10-22T11:38:14.383"
   id_USUARIO: 2
   nom_USUARIO: "timon"
   usu_USUARIO: "local2
```

Entonces puedes implementar la destructuración en `fnRespuestaObtener()` así:

```
function fnRespuestaObtener(rpta){
  const {apell_USUARIO,contra_USUARIO,fec_REG_USUARIO,id_USUARIO,nom_USUARIO,usu_USUARIO} = rpta.obtenerUsuario;

  if(id==id_USUARIO){
    $('#txtId').val(id_USUARIO);
    $('#txtNombres').val(nom_USUARIO);
    $('#txtApellidos').val(apell_USUARIO);
    $('#txtUsuario').val(usu_USUARIO);
    $('#txtContrasena').val(contra_USUARIO);
  }

}
```

Comment: genial ,¿ como los imprimo en los input de html?

Comment: Usando JQuery con selectores y `.val()`

Comment: un ejemplo porfavor amigo , si no es molestia :)

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, te explico como puedes hacerlo, en este caso utilizo un json api publico, en tu caso utiliza el tuyo, pero el funcionamiento es el mismo.

primero tienes que saber como llega tu request `axios` es por eso que te pedi el console.log, pero creo que es el primero, en todo caso tendrias que mostrarlo como lo hago dentro de la `fnRespuestaObtener`, de tal manera que puedas rellenar tu input.

PDTA. Use `Jquery` para rellenar el input, pero podrías hacerlo con `Javascript`, deje ambos de ejemplo.

```js
function fnObtener() {
  axios.post('https://www.londonprayertimes.com/api/times/?format=json&key=2a99f189-6e3b-4015-8fb8-ff277642561d&24hours=true', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  }, {}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    fnRespuestaObtener(response.data);
  })
}

function fnRespuestaObtener(rpta) {
  $('#prueba').val(rpta.city)
  document.getElementById("prueba2").value = rpta.date;
}
fnObtener();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='prueba' />
<input id='prueba2' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría algo así:

```
$.each(rpta.obtenerUsuario, function(key,value){
 nombre.text=String(value["nom_USUARIO"]);
 apellido.text=String(value["apell_USUARIO"]);
 usuario.text=String(value["usu_USUARIO"]);
 contrasea.text=String(value["contra_USUARIO"]);
)};
```

Por cada dato devuelto en el JSON es un ciclo, al indicarle que el ciclo se realice en "rpta.obtenerUsuario" buscara en este cuantos registros existen, y al existir solo uno los va a setear' los valores encontrados con los alias específicos que le indiques.

Comment: ¿y este código que realizaría?, revisar [answer].

Comment: Es un ciclo, por cada dato devuelto en el JSON es un cliclo, al indicarle que el ciclo se realice en "rpta.obtenerUsuario" buscara en este cuantos registros existen, y al existir solo uno los va a setear' los valores encontrados con los alias específicos que le indiques.

Comment: Gracias Hector, trata de agregar esa información a tus preguntas y te aseguro serán de utilidad para más usuarios de la comunidad.