# Cargar formato JSON a tabla

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un archivo Excel que estoy transformando a formato JSON para cargar una tabla HTML.

Su funcionamiento debe ser, descargar el archivo Excel e internamente el programa debe convertir esos registros en formato JSON y después pintar la tabla con registros. El problema es que al cargar la tabla se llena de `Undefined`

Tengo todo el código linea por linea descrito como funciona. Lo más probable es que este cometiendo algún error en alguna parte del código por ello no me carga los registros.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Tabla Filtrable</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/ccode39" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Tabla de Desarrolladores </h2>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Seleccione archivo Excel</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <input type="file" id="excel_file" />

        </div>
    </div>

 </div>

 <div id="datos">
    <div id="excel_data" class="mt-1"></div>
 </div>

    <div class="app">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Filtrar por desarrollador..."/>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Edad</th>
              <th>Lenguaje</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="names">
           
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
//recupera un elemento del documento HTML con el id "excel_file" y lo asigna a la variable `excel_file`.
//El elemento puede ser un elemento de entrada de tipo "archivo" que permite al usuario seleccionar un archivo de Excel desde su dispositivo.
const excel_file = document.getElementById('excel_file');

    //escucha un evento de cambio en un elemento con el id `excel_file`. Cuando se activa el evento de cambio,
    //se ejecutará el código dentro de la función de escucha de eventos. En este caso, el parámetro de evento 
    //se pasa a la función, que representa el objeto de evento.
    excel_file.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

    //Esta condición comprueba si el tipo del archivo seleccionado es 
    if(!['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'].includes(event.target.files[0].type))
    {
        //Establece el HTML interno del elemento con el id "excel_data", "alerta alerta-peligro" 
        //"Solo permite formato de archivo .xlsx o .xls". Muestra mensaje al seleccionar archivo con formato no válido.
        document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xlsx or .xls file format are allowed</div>';

        excel_file.value = '';

        return false;
    }
   //crea nueva instancia del objeto FileReader. El objeto lee contenido de archivos de varios formatos  
   //(texto, datos binarios o como ArrayBuffer) de forma asincrona
    var reader = new FileReader();

    //API de FileReader para leer un archivo como un ArrayBuffer
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
    
    //Función de controlador de eventos que se activa cuando se carga un archivo mediante la API de FileReader. 
    //especifica las acciones que desea realizar con el archivo cargado.
    reader.onload = function(event){
 
        //crea nuevo objeto `Uint8Array` a partir de la propiedad `reader.result`. `Uint8Array` es una matriz de enteros sin signo de 8 bits.
        // Usado para manejar datos binarios, como leer y manipular datos de archivos.
        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

        //biblioteca `XLSX` para leer la matriz `data` y crear un objeto del libro de trabajo
        var work_book = XLSX.read(data, {type:'array'});

        //recupera nombres de todas las hojas en el objeto del libro de trabajo `work_book` 
        //utilizando la propiedad `SheetNames`.
        var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;
        
        //El método `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json()` convierte los datos en la 1° hoja del objeto del libro de trabajo `work_book` en un objeto JSON.
        //El método `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json()` convierte los datos de una hoja en un objeto JSON. 
        //Toma dos parámetros: el objeto de hoja y un objeto de configuración opcional.
        var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], {header:1});
        //console.log(sheet_data);

        let names=document.querySelector('#names');
        names.innerHTML='';
        for(let item of sheet_data){
            names.innerHTML+= `
            <tr>
            <td>${item.Nombre}</td>
            <td>${item.Edad}</td>
            <td>${item.Lenguaje}</td>
            </tr>
            `
        }
 }
    
    });
```

Comment: Hola Juan, te recomiendo leer [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre JSON y un objeto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/164943/16597). Saludos!

Comment: Hola juan he visto que tienes varias preguntas con respuestas. Recuerda que debes marcar alguna como aceptada si te han ayudado a resolver tu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasa que `sheet_data` es una array de array's, No un array de objetos que es como tu lo presentas. Es decir:

- item.Nombre -> No existe
- item[0] -> Si existe

Te dejo el código corregido, además agregué que tome la primera fila como cabecera y las siguientes como contenido. Si tu caso no es así, basta que elimines ese trozo de código.

```js
//recupera un elemento del documento HTML con el id "excel_file" y lo asigna a la variable `excel_file`.
//El elemento puede ser un elemento de entrada de tipo "archivo" que permite al usuario seleccionar un archivo de Excel desde su dispositivo.
const excel_file = document.getElementById('excel_file');

    //escucha un evento de cambio en un elemento con el id `excel_file`. Cuando se activa el evento de cambio,
    //se ejecutará el código dentro de la función de escucha de eventos. En este caso, el parámetro de evento 
    //se pasa a la función, que representa el objeto de evento.
          excel_file.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

              //Esta condición comprueba si el tipo del archivo seleccionado es 
              if (!['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'].includes(event.target.files[0].type)) {
                  //Establece el HTML interno del elemento con el id "excel_data", "alerta alerta-peligro" 
                  //"Solo permite formato de archivo .xlsx o .xls". Muestra mensaje al seleccionar archivo con formato no válido.
                  document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xlsx or .xls file format are allowed</div>';

                  excel_file.value = '';

                  return false;
              }
              //crea nueva instancia del objeto FileReader. El objeto lee contenido de archivos de varios formatos  
              //(texto, datos binarios o como ArrayBuffer) de forma asincrona
              var reader = new FileReader();

              //API de FileReader para leer un archivo como un ArrayBuffer
              reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

              //Función de controlador de eventos que se activa cuando se carga un archivo mediante la API de FileReader. 
              //especifica las acciones que desea realizar con el archivo cargado.
              reader.onload = function (event) {

                  //crea nuevo objeto `Uint8Array` a partir de la propiedad `reader.result`. `Uint8Array` es una matriz de enteros sin signo de 8 bits.
                  // Usado para manejar datos binarios, como leer y manipular datos de archivos.
                  var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

                  //biblioteca `XLSX` para leer la matriz `data` y crear un objeto del libro de trabajo
                  var work_book = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });

                  //recupera nombres de todas las hojas en el objeto del libro de trabajo `work_book` 
                  //utilizando la propiedad `SheetNames`.
                  var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;

                  //El método `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json()` convierte los datos en la 1° hoja del objeto del libro de trabajo `work_book` en un objeto JSON.
                  //El método `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json()` convierte los datos de una hoja en un objeto JSON. 
                  //Toma dos parámetros: el objeto de hoja y un objeto de configuración opcional.
                  var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], { header: 1 });



//DE AQUÍ HACIA ABAJO CAMBIÉ!!!!!!!!!


                  //Esto si es que el Excel tiene cabeceras ===========
                  let cabecera = document.querySelector('#cabecera_table');

                  cabecera.innerHTML = '';
                  for (let item of sheet_data.shift()) {
                      cabecera.innerHTML += `<td>${item}</td>`;
                  }

                  //=====================================================


                  let names = document.querySelector('#names');
                  names.innerHTML = sheet_data
                      .map(fila => 
                          `<tr>
                            ${fila.map(celda => `<td>${celda}</td>`).join("")}
                           </tr>`)
                      .join("");
              }
          });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Tabla Filtrable</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/ccode39" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Tabla de Desarrolladores </h2>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Seleccione archivo Excel</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <input type="file" id="excel_file" />

        </div>
    </div>

 </div>

 <div id="datos">
    <div id="excel_data" class="mt-1"></div>
 </div>

    <div class="app">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Filtrar por desarrollador..."/>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr id="cabecera_table">
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="names">
           
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Notar que la parte HTML, en el thead de la tabla, realicé unos pequeños cambios**

Comment: Ok, asunto solucionado. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema se da porque el método [`XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json`](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/api/utilities/array#array-output) devuelve un arreglo de arreglos y no un arreglo de objetos como vos lo estas trabajando.

Por ejemplo, si el archivo Excel contiene la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El método `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json` devuelve:

```
[
  ["Nombre","Edad","Lenguaje"],
  ["Juan",16,"Español"]
]
```

> *Comentario al paso: El nombre del método no sería muy adecuado, ya que no devuelve un JSON*

#### Solución 1:

Leer los datos como vienene, en arreglo de arrelgos

```javascript
sheet_data.shift(); // OPCIONAL: Sacamos la primer fila
for (let item of sheet_data) {
  names.innerHTML += `<tr>
    <td>${item[0]}</td>
    <td>${item[1]}</td>
    <td>${item[2]}</td>
  </tr>`
}
```

#### Solución 2:

Al obtener `sheet_data` indicamos que nos devuelve un arreglo de objetos con las columnas como claves

```javascript
var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], { header: 'A' });
sheet_data.shift(); // OPCIONAL: Sacamos la primer fila
for (let item of sheet_data) {
  names.innerHTML += `<tr>
    <td>${item.A}</td>
    <td>${item.B}</td>
    <td>${item.C}</td>
  </tr>`
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado por la solución, también lo considerare.

Comment: Estimado, con tu solución me están saliendo unas comillas simples en los registros de la primer columna.

Comment: No se como poder copiarte una imagen donde en la primera columna se  observa en la tabla en cada fila innumerables comillas simple

Comment: Consulta adicional, como el archivo Excel tiene como 30 columnas quiero escoger solo algunos encabezado para tenerlo fijo en mi tabla cual seria la modificación? : por ejemplo yo solo necesito las columnas del Excel como encabezado{9,17,18,24,25, 43,44,20, 21, 22} en ese orden

Comment: Hola @JuanAlberto, disculpa, no entiendo donde se te presenta la dificultad. Si sabes que la primer fila contiene los encabezados y sabes en el orden que lo queres mostrar ¿que evita que lo hagas?

Comment: Detallo lo siguiente: el archivo Excel tiene 50 columnas, para cargar la tabla html solo necesito 10 columnas del Excel que son las columnas {9,17,18,24,25, 44,45,20, 21, 22} en ese orden. El código que tengo copia el contenido completo de la hoja de Excel (todas las columnas del Excel).

Comment: Hola @JuanAlberto, si utilizas la primer solución que te di en mi respuesta, no hay complejidad en lograr lo que necesitas. No importa la cantidad de columnas que tenga el Excel, es tán simple como indicar el indice correspondiente a la columna. O ¿el problema que tenes es que no sabes como adaptar el código?

Comment: estoy tratando de adaptar el código pero aun no lo consigo

Answer (score 0):

ya logre resolver mi duda, el inconveniente estaba en el for. Hay que reemplazar por este for.

```
// Obtener el elemento de la tabla HTML 
        var tableBody = document.getElementById('names'); 
        // Iterar sobre los datos y agregar filas a la tabla 
        for (var i = 0; i < sheet_data.length; i++) { 
            var row = tableBody.insertRow(i); 
            // Iterar sobre las columnas y agregar celdas a la fila 
            for (var j = 0; j < sheet_data[i].length; j++) { 
                var cell = row.insertCell(j); 
                cell.innerHTML = sheet_data[i][j]; 
            } 
        }
```