# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, vscode

estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de implementar el listado de clientes de mi API en mi app React. Me da este error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código en el cuál me da este error, si me pudierais ayudar os lo agradecería.

```
// Acción para obtener y listar clientes con filtrado
export const fetchCustomers = (queryParams) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(actions.startCall());

  return requestFromServer.getCustomers(queryParams).then((response) => {
    const values = response.data.data?.map((d) => ({
      id_customer: d.id_customer,
      name: d.name,
      vat_number: d.vat_number,
      contact_name: d.contact_name,
      prepaid: d.prepaid,
      date: d.date,
    }));
    let entities = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(values));
    let totalCount = entities.length;
    dispatch(actions.list({ totalCount, entities }));
  });
};
```

getCustomers

```
// Función para obtener clientes según un filtro proporcionado
export function getCustomers(filter) {
  // Convierte las claves del filtro en argumentos de consulta para la URL
  let keysFilter = Object.keys(filter);
  let newArguments = "";

  for (const keyFilter of keysFilter) {
    newArguments += keyFilter + "=" + filter[keyFilter] + "&";
  }
  // Realiza una solicitud GET con los filtros proporcionados
  return axios.get(`${CUSTOMERS_URL}/filter?${newArguments}`, {
    mode: "cors", // Configuración CORS para la solicitud
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Permitir acceso desde cualquier origen
    },
  });
}
```

Cuando hago una petición en el PostMan me aparece esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He modificado algunas partes del código para poder mostrar los console.log pertitnentes. No sé si esto ayudará a solucionar este problema que tengo. No creo que sea problema de la APi, pero por si acaso os mando eso.

```
export const fetchCustomers = (queryParams) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(actions.startCall());
  console.log("fetchCustomers iniciado. QueryParams:", queryParams);
  try {
    const response = await requestFromServer.getCustomers(queryParams);

    console.log("Response a secas:", response);
    console.log("Datos de clientes:", response.data);

    // Parsea la cadena JSON dentro de response.data.data
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(response.data.data);

    // Comprueba si 'data' en jsonData es un objeto antes de intentar acceder a 'data.data'
    if (jsonData.data && typeof jsonData.data === "object") {
      // Ahora puedes acceder a jsonData.data.data
      const values = jsonData.data.data.map((d) => ({
        id_customer: d.id_customer,
        name: d.name,
        vat_number: d.vat_number,
        contact_name: d.contact_name,
        prepaid: d.prepaid,
        date: d.date,
      }));

      console.log("Values:", values);

      let entities = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(values));
      let totalCount = entities.length;
      dispatch(actions.list({ totalCount, entities }));
    } else {
      console.log("La estructura de 'data' no es la esperada:", jsonData);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(actions.catchError({ error, type: "list" }));
  }
};
```

Esto me muestra por consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te estás liando al usar `JSON.parse` por varios motivos:

1. Tienes lo siguiente:

```javascript
console.log("Response a secas:", response);
console.log("Datos de clientes:", response.data);
```

Ambas trazas se muestran en tu consola, por lo que response NO es un string. Eso significa que NO es un JSON (más detalles sobre esto [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto/)).

2. Si usas `JSON.parse` sobre `response.data.data`, y sobre el resultado estás buscando datos en `jsonData.data.data`, es el equivalente a usar

```javascript
response.data.data.data.data
```

3. Usar JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) sólo sirve para clonar el objeto, quitándole funciones.

Por tanto, tu código debería ser algo como:

```javascript
// getCustomers devuelve ya un objeto
const response = await requestFromServer.getCustomers(queryParams);
const entities = response.data.map(d => ({
        id_customer: d.id_customer,
        name: d.name,
        vat_number: d.vat_number,
        contact_name: d.contact_name,
        prepaid: d.prepaid,
        date: d.date,
      })
)
dispatch(actions.list({ entities.length, entities }));
```

Comment: He modificado el enunciado del problema por si ves dónde puede estar mi error. Gracias de antemano por tu ayuda

Comment: Respuesta actualizada

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @pablo , era tema del backend por eso no me funcionaba